# C# and WPF - Dataset to DataGrid - join two tables in Dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, dataset, wpfdatagrid

I would like to solve one problem I ran into while I was making application that can help to show and modify data in Access Database using C# WPF program.

What I have - to clarify it - it is a Database I have access to. Database contains three tables and relationships. There are also some queries because in past it completely worked on VBA.

Now I got a request to do a user-friendly app for this DB (database).

What I can do is load data from main table let me say table " Parts ". This table contains some parts data such as ID, name, group ID etc. 
There is also another table called Group. Group contains 3 group names. For instance it could be Software, Hardware, Other.

If I were user and knew SQL I would write: EDIT:/edited select

```
SELECT ID, Parts.Name , Parts.Group , GroupName.Group from PARTS 
LEFT JOIN Group ON Parts.GroupID = Group.ID
```

This is also created in QUERY in Access DB file. 
And it gives you View as you like after clicking on this view - still in VBA in Access DB file.

What I did in C# was that I loaded all the tables that DB contains.

and I have

```
ds.Tables["Parts"]
ds.Tables["Groups"]
```

When you assign

```
DataView dv = new DataView;
dv = DataSet.Tables["Parts"].DefalutView; 
//PreviouslyCretedDatagridInWPF:
dataGrid.DataSource = dv;
```

If you load application, loading of Grid works fast and I can have window loaded in one second - data in "parts " table- there are approx 10,000 rows and 27 columns.

But If I try to do some Join using a for instance with simple If condition so sth like

`ds.Tables["TempParts"]` can also be just a simple cloned table with one string type added column on position e.g. 28.

```
for(i=0;i<ds.Tables["Parts"].Rows.Count;i++) {     
    for( j=0;j<ds.tables["groups"].Rows.Count;j++){
    //0is ID column//10is groupIDcolumn)
    if(ds.Tables["TempParts"].Rows[i][10] == ds.Tables["groups"].Rows[j][0]) 
     { ds.Tables["TempParts"].Rows[i][28]= ds.Tables["groups"].Rows[j][0];}
}
```

So I can somehow assign or perform join like this. but i feel this is not the right or best way how to do it. Because this I am asking weather there is a way to do it more convenient or even faster because this is really time consumable operation.

The next step is of course showing the clicked row in new window and do some edits and apply using accept changes so I used if condition also in edit window but I wrote it manually that means if user selects " hardware " it assign number 1 to groupID column in Parts table I feel this is also not the correct way to do it or is it?

I count with a case that also table groups in future will be editable so "groups" and ID cant be stored in some static array or struct or so. Well I have to work with loaded data in data tables.

So what I would like to do is perform join above my dataset and than if I select some row and edit I would like also check what ID belongs to e.g. GroupID text value which is shown for user like I mentioned "software" " hardware" etc. and assign this id to primary data table and accept changes ...

Question is what is the faster / convenient way to do this.

Do it above (in) DB, do it with code itself, use some library which can perform such operations quicker?

There can be some mistake of course in code because I do not have the real code here and I tried to simplify it as much as I could.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please ask one question a time. Your select query looks suspicious. It should probably be `parts.groupid=group.id`

Comment: Yes I made it right to clarify it. And for sure. This is just one question. Point is how to perform such select and show it in datagrid correctly.